# Orbit camera (C++, GLM)

Tags: c++, opengl, math, camera, glm-math

I'm trying to write the orbital camera (based on glm::quat) for my OpenGL application.
I have a few questions:

1. Сan I make ViewMatrix from RotationMatrix + position of camera?

   camera_quat = glm::quat(glm::vec3(tmp_pitch, tmp_yaw, 0)) * camera_quat;

   ```
   float pitch = camera_quat.pitch();
   float yaw = camera_quat.yaw();

   glm::mat4 rotate = glm::mat4_cast(camera_quat);

   glm::vec3 view_direction(cos(yaw) * cos(pitch), sin(pitch), -sin(yaw) * cos(pitch));
   camera_position = target - view_direction * radius;

   glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(camera_position);

   glm::mat4 view_matrix = **???**;
   ```
2. Is this line correct?: 
   `glm::vec3 view_direction(cos(yaw) * cos(pitch), sin(pitch), -sin(yaw) * cos(pitch));`

P.S. Sorry if my english is bad. It is not my native language, I am russian.
I hope you can help me. Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you have a quaternion, why are you using Euler angles like yaw, pitch, and roll?

Comment: I began to use quaternions recently... Newbie in this case :(

Comment: I'm trying to rotate the camera around a some object by the gamepad stick. tmp_(yaw/pitch) let me construct temporary quat for a single frame

Comment: What is the orbital camera? Can you explain that?

Comment: Yes of course. "Orbit camera": 1)camera position is in the area circumscribed around the object ("target") 2)eye_direction = normalize(target - camera_position)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change the `translate` matrix to

```
glm::mat4 translate = glm::translate(-camera_position);
```

, it should be simply

```
glm::mat4 view_matrix = rotation * translation;
```

However, there is an easier way to go there. What you basically want to do is the following: Move the camera to the target, rotate the camera there, move it a bit back. This can be expressed in matrix form with (note that the view matrix is the inverse model transform for the camera):

```
view_matrix = glm::translate(0, 0, -radius) * rotate * glm::translate(-target);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. 
But could you explain why we are taking a negative value of target and radius? I really can not understand this part of the solution...

target - position in world space, right?

Comment: Yes, target position is in world space. The view matrix does not have the purpose of positioning an object (the camera). Instead it has the purpose of transforming the scene, such that the camera will be at the origin. That is why all participating matrices are inverted (I assume the rotation matrix is already inverted) and in reverse order.

Comment: Oh, I see! So I can replace it with glm::inverse(glm::translate(0, 0, radius) * rotate * glm::translate(target)), right? (rotation matrix is not inverted)
I must simply invert a model matrix?

If it is, thanks for the answer! You helped me a lot, thank you very much again!

Comment: If you also reverse the order of the matrices, then this should be fine.